# How to configure a Surface 3 tablet to use the front-facing camera for Zoom?

Tags: windows-10, video, zoom-meeting, meetings, microsoft-surface-3

For a Microsoft Surface 3 [tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_3), joining a zoom meeting activates the rear camera.  How can I use the [front-facing camera](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro7-surfmusic/front-camera-not-working-for-skype-or-zoom/b4c1108f-28da-4b2e-a039-eeca5de66cdb) for a zoom meeting?

I'm using the webpage to join a meeting.

Comment: You should be able to select which device you want to Zoom to use within the application settings.  Have you tried doing that?  The default device more than likely is the rear-facing camera.  I have a Surface Pro 3, I just don't use Zoom, and won't install it for privacy reasons (which is required to properly answer this question).

Answer (score 1):

Normally Zoom lets you set the camera in Settings 》Video. If you don't have this option, then keep on reading.

The Microsoft Surface has two cameras, one front-facing and one rear-facing.

Depending on which camera you want to use, you can either enable or disable
these cameras in the Device Manager:

- Run Device Manager from the Start menu
- Scroll down to and expand System Devices
- Double click on either "Microsoft Camera Front" or "Microsoft Camera Rear"
- In the Driver tab, select "Enable Device" on the camera that you want to use,
  and select "Disable Device" on the other.

If both cameras are enabled, you should be able to choose any of them.